# How to pass a keyEvent object to a Button to let it appears like clicked?

Tags: android, surfaceview

i have made a surfaceView to accept a OnTouchEvent,and in this view, i draw a Button manually with Button.draw(Canvas)(not make a ViewGroup).

now, this button can be drawn on my SurfaceView, but when i pass a keyEvent from OnTouchEvent to Button like Button.onTouchEvent(keyEvent), but this button cannot show the click effect

so the question is how can i pass the keyEvent to a View manully and it show what it shown in a Layout????

Any ideas?thx!!

Comment: if you see my source code, you'll notice, by calling `setPressed(true)`, the button gets the click effect. then after a small delay its turned off `setPressed(false)`. you'll need to code that into your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this...but i couldn't figure it out. So here's what i came up with.

I created my own extension of `Button`. And create components of `MyButton` inside my `xmls`.

```
<com.stackoverflow.android.example.MyButton android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.stackoverflow.android.example.MyButton>
```

You'll need to change every instance of `Button` to `com.stackoverflow.android.example.MyButton`.

```
package com.stackoverflow.android.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyButton extends Button {

    final int MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_ON = 0;
    final int MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_OFF = 1;

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_ON:
                setPressed(true);
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_OFF, ViewConfiguration.getPressedStateDuration());
                break;
            case MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_OFF:
                setPressed(false);
            default:
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    public void performVirtualClick()
    {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_MYBUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_ON);
        performClick();

    }

}
```

Call the `performVirtualClick` function...that'll do.